# boxBoxAPIJSONOperation is encoded as x-www-form-urlencoded, not JSON

Tags: box-api

Using box-ios-sdk-v2 (v1.1.1):

```
BoxAPIJSONOperation *operation = [[BoxAPIJSONOperation alloc] initWithURL:myTokenURL
                                                               HTTPMethod:BoxAPIHTTPMethodPOST
                                                                     body:POSTParams
                                                              queryParams:nil
                                                            OAuth2Session:self];
```

This operation is generated with a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Shouldn't it be `application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the bug report. You're right that the SDK should be setting the content-type to application/json when it sends JSON over the wire. The Box V2 API is currently not strictly validating content types of request bodies, which is why we missed this.

I've pushed a fix and cut a new release on GitHub: https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2/releases/tag/v1.1.2

New podspec is coming soon.